# all my android app stops while starting

Tags: android

The following is the error log,if you know ,and thanks for your help!

```
I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut; interface 2051 'Lcom/blueware/agent/android/api/v2/TraceFieldInterface;'
W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut;' failed
W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityEclair; (383)
W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityEclair;' failed
W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb; (384)
W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb;' failed
W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityJB; (385)
W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityJB;' failed
W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity; (386)
W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;' failed
W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity; (400)
W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;' failed
W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lorg/wangchenlong/contentproviderdemo/MainActivity; (1535)
W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lorg/wangchenlong/contentproviderdemo/MainActivity;' failed
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4159dbd8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo, PID: 13257
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo/org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2116)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13257 SIG: 9
```

Comment: did you see that error log?

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.wangchenlong.contentproviderdemo.MainActivity"`

Comment: You declared the class in the Manifest.xml ?

Comment: Check your package name and Activity name all are mention properly in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your Activity in your Manifest file?
Check your full Actitivity name too. The error can be related to a typo or wrong package name.

```
<application> 
    <activity android:name="com.mysampleapp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity"> </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: yes,i do.and its Okay after restart. but its appeared usually,and i think its for java8s sake